# Alternative to Jtable plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-jtable

The jtable that could be found here http://jtable.org is already a best one for me. But they said that it becomes slow when handling lots of data.

So is there an alternative for this that also has the same CRUD functionality and could handle multiple data without sacrificing the speed?

Comment: jqGrid and jQuery DataTables, jTables might be becoming slow for specific browsers or a specific reason.  You can always change it to Server Side Paging.

Comment: @abc123 , The default of jtable is client side paging? does making it server side paging included in their documentation?

Comment: It is in data tables and jqGrid I'm sure it is in the jtables documentation as well

Answer (score 4):

I have used DataTables (https://datatables.net) and I can say it's working pretty good and easy to customize/extend the functionalities.

Answer (score 3):

Speed becomes an issue normally when your record set is very large in **IE**.  If this is the case for you it is normally the size of the page, as **IE** doesn't handle large `DOM`'s very well.

To solve this problem you should look into switching to `server side paging and sorting`.

[Paging and Sorting in jTable Server Side](http://www.jtable.org/demo/pagingandsorting)

For other `alternatives` to `jTable`:

[DataTables](https://datatables.net/)
[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

Both of these alternatives support Server Side Paging, Sorting, and Searching.

But it is a common issue that **IE** runs slower on these Table libraries with large `Result Sets`.

*This answer is an expansion of my earlier comment.*

Answer (score 1):

The "datatable" solution you choose should really support "server-side paging" if you're loading so much data that your tables are performing badly

- **[Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/)** will allow you to do this, see for a specific example http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html for a specific example
- **[Dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com/)** is another alternative and supports server-side pagination. The documentation seems a lot easier to understand that datatables, see http://www.dynatable.com/#json-from-ajax for a specific example

Just be aware that this will potentially mean more requests to your server as you are moving the processing from the client to the server